# Get homepage content with PHP curl() and push the result into a Flash player with actionscript

Tags: image, curl

It's a freak question, but can you offer me any working solution in flash?

I want to create a website tester, so I want to get the external homepage and render it to the Flash... If it's an image or the full website I accept both.

I remember! Same as http://www.thumbalizr.com/ just ratio 1:1.

Is there any opensource script for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [wkhtmltopng](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/); IIRC it has PHP bindings also - note that it needs X installed *on the server*.